# Are array elements incomplete objects?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

After a [recent question on static typing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18988080/596781), I was thinking about arrays again. I always thought that array elements are just ordinary objects, but now I wonder:

Are the elements of an array complete objects in their own right, or are they incomplete, and the only complete object is the array itself?

If this were the case, then what is the complete object of `(new T[N])[0]`, and what is its type?

If the element is incomplete, then does that mean that there are complete objects whose type cannot be known statically? (This is different from base/derived business: the type of `new Derived` *is* known statically, though it may never be recorded outside that expression.)

Comment: what do you mean by 'complete object'.  My personal interpretation of the word 'object' is 'block of memory'.  The array will have a N lumps of memory equal to sizeof(T).  the type of an element of an array of 'T' is probably compiler implementation defined but it would be sufficient to say that is is effectively 'T' but will act as a T&.

Comment: I guess Angew explains what a complete object is in his answer.

Comment: @Pete: The term "complete object" is defined in the language.

Comment: @zygoloid: Objects confuse me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array element is not a complete object. C++11, [intro.object]§2:

> Objects can contain other objects, called *subobjects.* A subobject can be a *member subobject* (9.2), a *base class subobject* (Clause 10), or an array element. An object that is not a subobject of any other object is called a *complete object.*

As for `(new T[N])[0]`. The complete object is the object created by the *new-expression* (an array of `T`). I'd say its type is "array of `N` elements of `T`", as per [expr.new]§1:

> The *new-expression* attempts to create an object of the *type-id* or *new-type-id* to which it is applied.

Here, it's a *new-type-id,* constructed from `T[N]`.

Note that when creating arrays, a *new-expression* returns a pointer to the initial element of that array, not to the array itself. Which means that in such case, the type of the *new-expression* is not the type of the complete object it creates. In other words, the complete object's type cannot be accessed by any means.

Comment: But N can be different from zero.

Comment: @selalerer Whoops, I misparsed the parentheses. Thanks for the correction. I will amend the answer.

Comment: Great, thanks -- I find it interesting that there are types in C++ which cannot be known statically, and also that there doesn't seem to be any feasible operation of "completion of an object". It's a purely theoretical concept that cannot be implemented as an operation within the language.

Comment: @Angew AFAIK the return type of new is a pointer to the new-type-id.

Comment: @selalerer No, it's not. Check `[expr.new]§5`: "When the allocated object is an array (that is, the *noptr-new-declarator* syntax is used or the *new-type-id* or *type-id* denotes an array type), the *new-expression* yields a pointer to the initial element (if any) of the array. [ Note: both `new int` and `new int[10]` have type `int*` and the type of `new int[i][10]` is `int (*)[10]` —end note ]"