# new[] if element default constructor can throw?

Tags: c++

consider the following code:

```
example_t* a = new example_t[8];
```

class `example_t` has default ctor that can throw, suppose construction of 5th element in array throws. Is there automatic call to destructor of the 4 first elements? Is it a well defined behavior?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is perfectly well-defined and well-behaved. All completely constructed subobjects are destroyed if the initialization of an object terminates with an exception, in reverse order of their construction. This is the same for arrays as it is for objects of user-defined type (think classes and class members).

Formally, we have  C++11 15.2/2:

> An object of any storage duration whose initialization or destruction is terminated by an exception will
>   have destructors executed for all of its fully constructed subobjects (excluding the variant members of a
>   union-like class), that is, for subobjects for which the principal constructor (12.6.2) has completed execution
>   and the destructor has not yet begun execution.

Comment: +1 Well there you go. Thanks sir! Is the *order* of destruction unspecified and left to the implementation? (the order [in this sample](http://ideone.com/BHZWo4) is interesting to me.

Comment: @WhozCraig: No, the order must be specified (think about newer things referring to older things). Let me see if I can find a formal statement.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I can't see it *not* specified *somewhere*  It is to great detail for automatic objects in-scope or members of some objet, so I would think it here as well.

Comment: From §12.2/5: *If the lifetime of two or more temporaries to which references are bound ends at the same point, these temporaries are destroyed at that point in the reverse order of the completion of their construction.* I can't see why this would be an exception to the rule.

Comment: There are lots of "hints" why this should be the case. E.g. 15.2/1 says that *automatic* objects are destroyed in reverse order, and 5.3.5/6 says that *complete* arrays are destroyed in reverse order, and 12.4/8 says that class members are destroyed in reverse order.

Comment: +1 It seems better quote than mine, I think my quote is addressing the same thing too.

Comment: Spec can be tricky to read. Array is considered "Object with initializer" and elements are considered subobjects which is not trivial.

Comment: @Muxecoid, M.M.: I don't think anyone was confused that array elements are subobjects (but see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19132671/596781)), and I'm not sure if the edit was necessary. In any event, I still don't see how this answers the destruction order in the event of an exception.

Comment: It appears that the destruction *order* may be unspecified for non-automatic arrays in C++11; this may be a defect in the language.

Answer (score 9):

Per § 5.3.4 / 8:

> A new-expression obtains storage for the object by calling an
>   allocation function (3.7.4.1). **If the new-expression terminates by
>   throwing an exception, it may release storage by calling a
>   deallocation function** (3.7.4.2). If the allocated type is a non-array
>   type, the allocation function’s name is operator new and the
>   deallocation function’s name is operator delete. If the allocated type
>   is an array type, the allocationfunction’s name is operator new[] and
>   the deallocation function’s name is operator delete[].

They will be deleted since deallocation function will invokes destructors.

---

I know leaning on compiler's ouput is not trust-able, but it's at least a good observation: [Live Test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de09000d7a296fc8)

Comment: The question was not about storage, it was about elements destructors.

Comment: I often give pause to embark on the deeper meaning of "may", especially in a sentence like *that*.

Comment: Doesn't a deallocation function (e.g. `delete`) invoke destructor?!

Comment: @MM. It would appear so. [See It Live](http://ideone.com/BHZWo4). But I'm curious if this is the only hint of a reference in the standard that objects that have completed destruction are destroyed, and ones that haven't, including the one that threw the exception, aren't (or so the sample would indicate). The ones that never even *saw* construction I can understand, but the one that threw is interesting to me. I also found the order of the objects-destroyed equally interesting.

Comment: @WhozCraig: You're test is more readable than mine (I've just added). I will take a look at standard to find another quote (if there is).

Comment: @MM. Don't kill yourself. They're two different tests (and I'm gonna edit your link text, as its bothering me =P) but I've tried it now on three different implementations and they all exhibit similarly.If you happened to find something, it would be great. (and +1, btw).

Comment: @MM.: Actually, deallocation functions *do not* invoke destructors; as their name imply they are solely concerned with deallocating storage. I believe that the compiler will introduce code at the call site to deal with this the destruction (in reverse order).

Comment: "operator delete[]" is subtly different from "delete[]" without "operator" :( Calling "delete[]" without "operator" will invoke destruction even for array elements not constructed yet (element 7 in question statement).